# How to init vector from other vector

Tags: c++

I have a question about std::vector in C++.
How can I put only few elements from first vector into second.
In vector constructor?
This is my code it doesn't work:

```
std::vector<int> a;
int i;
for (i=0;i<10;i++) a.at(i)=10;
std::vector<int> b(&a.at(4), &a.at(7));
```

I expected in vector b are elements from vector a[4] - a[7].
Could you  help me

Comment: You initialization of `b` is correct... It is the initialization of `a` which is not (missing `resize(10)`, or use `pusk_back`).

Comment: If you wonder why `a[7]` isn't there, then read the specification carefully, the end iterator is **one past the end of the range**.

Comment: C++ intervals are always half-open, so that would give you `a[4]` through `a[6]`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. Your code will throw on line three, so anything in line four is irrelevant.

Comment: This is a valid question but a not-so-good way to present it: question seeking for help should provide a [mcve], an expected behaviour and an observed behaviour; but this code would fail with an exception before reaching initialization of `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> a;
int i;
for (i=0;i<10;i++) a.at(i)=10;
```

This code will throw `std::out_of_range` exception since `a.size()` is zero.

`std::vector<int> b(&a.at(4), &a.at(7));`

This won't include `a[7]` as the constructor that takes two iterator/position is open ended, i.e. `[first, last)`. So `last` `a[7]` won't be included. If you want to include `a[7]` then you have to specify `a[8]` as closing interval.

`std::vector<int> b(&a.at(4), &a.at(8));`

Or

`std::vector<int> b(&a[4], &a[8]);`

But this won't work if `8` is out of range. So instead if using `at` or `operator[]` you should use iterator like @TerraPass already pointed:

`std::vector<int> b(a.cbegin() + 4, a.cbegin() + 8);`

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector<T>` has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)*, which accepts a pair of iterators. You could use it like this:

```
std::vector<int> b(a.cbegin() + 4, a.cbegin() + 7);
```

<sup>*See the 4th constructor signature on the linked page.</sup>

Note that this will not include `a[7]`, since, as @taskinoor points out, the second iterator is one past the end of the copied range. If you intend to also include `a[7]`, you should change the second argument to `a.cbegin() + 8`.

Comment: @taskinoor You're right, it won't include `a[7]`, I assumed that OP's `a[4] - a[7]` meant "up to `a[7]`". I'll add a note to my answer. Anyway, I believe your answer does a far better job of addressing the question, given the problems with OP's code.